# Handle message again aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

I need to replace 1 special character in the message

I have this function

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(contains='-g'))
async def g_replace(message: types.Message):
    message.text = message.text.lower().replace('-g', '').replace('г', 'ґ')
    # handle message again
```

After that I want to handle this message again with other handlers. Is it possible?

UPD: I don't want to handle message with the same handler, so I need the same result as if user have sent modified message.
So I can't use constructions like `other_handler(message)` or `this_handler(message)` because I don't know exactly which handler would handle that message

Comment: `other_handler(message)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem with **middlewares**, wich are somthing like handlers before handlers. First of all - import middleware class:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
```

After that, define class for middleware

```
class GPreFilter(BaseMiddleware):
def __init__(self):
    super(GPreFilter, self).__init__()

async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, *args):
    if '-g' in message.text.lower():
        message.text = message.text.lower().replace('-g', '').replace('г', 'ґ')
```

Aiogram automatically calls `on_process_message` when it is a new message. Then setup this middleware

```
dp.middleware.setup(GPreFilter())
```

Now all the messages will be handled by middleware, and then by handlers